# Which variables determines the champion select position?

Tags: league-of-legends

When I play duo ranked, my partner always gets first pick, and I'm last pick.

Sometimes I do duo queue with another person, and that person goes third, and I'm second.

The position is determined by which variables? elo? playing behaviour? wins/loses? league points?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the host of a group absorbs the chances of his invited mates for the firstpick. (didn't find a reference to that though i think i read in on the official site)

When taking the comment [here](http://www.newsoflegends.com/index.php/pick-order-in-champion-select-ward-tracking-buffs-to-jungle-and-stacking-items-ashes-passive-reworked-and-more-8990/) the chance to be firstpick should be 20%, when playing solo, as soon as you play with mates, and (given the case the previous assumption is correct and) you are not the host, you will never be firstpick.

> - Players with faster load times shouldn’t have an unfair advantage in Call Order
> - Pick Order occurs naturally in the current design, so it’s more intuitive
> - **Over time, players get an equal number of opportunities to be each pick slot**
> - Players shouldn’t have to race to type a position at the start of each match

On the other hand when you are the host, you will have more chances for first place, as you absorbed your mates' chances. Problem is, these still are only 40% at max. thus you might end up second.

Comment: Even if I'm the host (as always do) my duo partner always gets first pick and I'm last pick, so this isn't about chances or who set up the duo party: I discarded that already, except when I'm solo queue.

Comment: @Fabián wait.. you mean your partner is firstpick even if you are host??

Comment: That's right. Now, he's gold and I'm bronze, maybe it could be by elo, but could be the win ratio too, or wins/loses, league points... maybe another factor that I didn't think about before.

Comment: damn and I was so sure I had read it somewhere...

Comment: This is not relevant to ranked games. That's how it works in normal draft.

Comment: @Schism then i maybe even read it here...

Answer (score 0):

As I know when being in champ select in a ranked game The person with the highest elo comes first and the one with the lowest comes last.

Comment: Do you have a source for this?

Comment: That's what a friend told me, but would be great if you could provide the source to prove if it is for real.

Comment: I think I could try using the [lolnexus site](http://www.lolnexus.com/) each time I enter to draft mode, and check about the wins/loses or something..